# Uniform metric expressions on function space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any set and $(Y,d)$ be a metric space. Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be two functions. Is it true that 
 $\sup_{x\in X}(\min\{d(f(x),g(x)),1\})=\min \{\sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),g(x)),1\}$
 Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Left hand side is either $1$ or smaller than $1$. Consider the two cases.

Comment: I know they are both metric on $Y^X$ and they generate the same topology. Are you claiming they are same metric? Thanks.

Comment: @Neon: I haven't put any thought into whether or not they are metrics, and have yet to claim whether or not they are the same, but yes, they are.

Comment: @tomasz: Both sides are $\le 1$.

Comment: @tomasz: I changed my answer. Is it Okey?